# Avoid using angular.fromJson when receiving a JSON from a Web Method

Tags: c#, json, angularjs, asp-classic, webmethod

Good afternoon guys,

Right to the point: I have a ASP Web form in which i created a Web Method that i called asynchronously using Angular to populate an data on an HTML table using AngularJS directives.

Here's the code...
On aspx.cs:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]//Specify return format.
public static string GetJSON()
{
      DataTable dt = new DataTable();
      dt = GetData();
      var TheJSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt, Formatting.Indented);
      return TheJSON;
}
```

On my Angular service:

```
app.service("myService", function($http){
        this.post = function () {
            var promise = $http.post("/MyAspx.aspx/GetJSON", {data: {} }).then(function(result){
                return result.data.d;
            },function(err){
                console.log(err);
            });
            return promise;
        }
    });
```

On my Angular controller:

```
$scope.getDataClick = function(e){
      var prom = myService.post();
      prom.then(function(result){
           $scope.theData = angular.fromJson(result);
});
```

I got 2 problems, the first one is that for some reason I need to use the `angular.fromJson` function to convert the response into a JSON object even though I am using a JSON response format in my WebMethod. Why i want to avoid that? Because in the producion environment there are over 19k records and i am getting a message from the browser that because the script is taking too much time and it is happening when Angular is parsing (correct me if this is not the right term) the string into a JSON.

The second problem is that i am required to present all the data (all the 19k records :/ ) and that it needs to have filters and a search box, which i already have and works relatively fine with the 500+ records that i have on the development environment but it won't work on the production environment due to the amount of data. IS using an "Angular table" with an `ng-repeat` directive and filters the best approach? I can use pagination or maybe an infinite scrolling but then the filters and search box would need to look up the entire data and i do not know how to have that amount of data available to accomplish that.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're outputting 19k records in the browser? No wonder it's grinding to a halt. Doing withouth `.fromJson` will likely make no difference. I can't help but think you need to go back and argue the requirements. Nobody would be able to visually look through 19k records. So doing this all client-side seems very daft...

Comment: I completely agree with that. And the fromJson matter is just part of looking for a feasible solution for this.

Comment: The feasible solution would be to do server-side processing. 19k records in a browser is simply (sorry to say) stupid.

Comment: ... not to mention any 2-way binding you might be doing.. You could try bindonce (https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce) to massively reduce the number of watchers that get created. Other than that, 19k records is plain f***ed :)

Comment: Alright, beside that, any ideas on the "fromJson" part?

Comment: I would return a strongly types object, and not a datatable - such as a `List<MyItem>`. You shouldn't need to then parse the result has json. Or. Try returning `DataTable` and not string, and don't serialize it in your method; just return `dt`. Let the method do the rest.

Comment: doesn't make sense that you have to use `fromJson` when in the step before you didn't. Also why are you formatting the response?

Comment: Thanks Darrem. charlie if i do not use fromJson it won't work. I will check on the previous answer suggestions.